# Trigger events based on timestamp of embedded Soundcloud track

Tags: soundcloud

Is it possible trigger events based on the timestamp of an embedded Soundcloud track?

I would like to show/hide photos based on the content of the Soundcloud track but not able to find information about this in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats possible. Please share some code. What does embedded mean?

I assume you will use JS.

You can use ie timed comments.
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript

```
SC.stream("/tracks/293", {
  autoPlay: true,
  ontimedcomments: function(comments){
    console.log(comments[0].body);
  }
});
```

---

Or you can use the standard player events and use your own database.